# Tiny black flecks on squash and okra

Tags: diseases

What are tiny, size is the size of a tip of a needle, black flecks on squash and okra plants?  What needs to be done to save the plants?

Comment: photo would be useful, but they sound like maybe thrips or pollen beetles.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell without a picture or two. I'm assuming you'd have noticed if the specs were alive/moving. If the plants are still healthy, it's probably just dirt. Don't worry about it. But if there are holes in the leaves too, it might be insect droppings. Check the undersides of the leaves, the main stem, and in the top layer of soil for pests. If you find any insects, be sure you properly identify them before you treat for them, as most insects don't eat squash, and the ones you find may not be pests.